# package.json main for lerna + typescript setup

Tags: typescript, lerna

I have a lerna + ts setup:

```
lerna.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
packages:
  - core (@a/core)
      package.json: main = src/index.ts
      src:
        index.ts
  - webapp
```

When the main is set to `src/index.ts` it runs fine, however if I set core package's main to `dist/index.js`, which is my packaged `dist` when published to npm, the webapp will lose realtime update effect and only watch `dist` folder.

I understand the behavior but how can I set up to accommodate to both scenarios?